# postgress node.js function response not proper

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql

I have following code

```
function query(query) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
       
        pool.query(query, (err, res) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            // for (let row of res.rows) {
            //     console.log(row);
            // }
            resolve(res);
            pool.end();
        });
    });
}
```

getting results

```
{
    "rows": [
        {
            "fnsaveuser": {
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "is_new": 0,
                "login_id": 1,
                "user_name": "tesr user",
                "created_on": "2020-11-06"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How to get results only the response getting from function like

```
{
                "email": "test@test.com",
                "is_new": 0,
                "login_id": 1,
                "user_name": "tesr user",
                "created_on": "2020-11-06"
            }
```

function in db is

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public."fnsaveuser"(
    _data text
)
 RETURNS json
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
    
    begin
        return  jsonb_set( "fnGetUserDetails"()::jsonb , '{is_new}', '0', TRUE);
    END;
$function$
;
```

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking for, but I think you could do like something this: `result.rows[0]. fnsaveuser `

Comment: That i know but why I need to filter on function name as I have used in python and was getting response whatever being returned from  function....and I have gone through many examples on google and nowhere I have found where it is filtering on function name to get actual result... so I am thinking something I am doing wrong

Comment: I am not sure which postgres client you are using, `node-pg` ? Can we see your query? Is `fnsaveuser ` a jsonb column?

Comment: yes package is node-postgres and return from function is jsonb as json

Comment: I have updated the post with query as well

Comment: ok thanks, anyway `result.rows` is normal `node-pg` response: https://node-postgres.com/features/queries.
So you will have to extract the result yourself

Comment: You haven't shown the query in which you are actually calling the function? And no, you can't get a single result back - there are functions that return multiple rows, and there are functions that return multiple columns, so you always get an array as the result.

Comment: I have updated.... my issue is not returning array.. issue is why there is function name in response